# Maven Android Plugin

Tags: android, maven, plugins

I feel like I must be missing something.  There are a million references and guides to using the `maven-android-plugin`, but I cannot for the life of me find a mention of how to get/include it.

Is it something I just reference in my pom file?

My pom file throws an error on this line without it:

```
<packaging>apk</packaging>
```

Comment: This was a good reference to me: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/android-dev.html. Idk if you've already read it, or it helps.